# using var and not var keyword in C#

Tags: c#

i have some confusing about var and not var initialization.

```
var x=10;

x=12;
```

what is the difference between those initialization in  C# ?

i knew var is keyword is used for following kind of ways.

When the type is complex to write, such as a LINQ query (the reason for var in the first place) use var.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: There are a dozen or more dupes in the Related column on the right.

Comment: Peripheral note - `var` wasn't added purely for the convenience of not having to write out the declaring type.  The primary reason that it was added was because it was impossible to return anonymous types without it.  All the other reasons were extras that came along with it.

Answer (score 1):

This one compiles.

```
var x=10;
```

This one does not assuming you are trying to initialize x in this scenario.

```
x=12;
```

It has to be:

```
int x = 12;
```

Now what is the difference between `var x=12;` and `int x = 12;` nothing.  They are both resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is used to declare ***and*** assign a local variable `x`. The new variable declared will automatically get the (strong and non-dynamic) type of the right-hand side of the `=`. That is type `int` in your example.

The second one is used to assign (only) to a variable or property that has been declared already elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To use `var` keyword, there **must** be an expression which possesses a type on the right hand side of the equals (=) for it to compile.

`var myNumber = 1;` will work, as var will be compiled to int as a type.  `myNumber = 1` will not work, since myNumber is not declared.  If you want to declare a variable with nothing on the right side of the equals sign, then you must specify the type explicitly, i.e `int myNumber`.

Personally, I would only use var when it's obvious what it will compile to... e.g.

```
var myNumber = 1; 
var name = "some name"; 
var lst = List<int>();
```

less obvious...

```
var data = GetData();
```

Sure, you can go to the method to see what the return is, but it can be more difficult to read for other developers.

Comment: What's less readable is calling the variable "x".

Comment: @christiandev - it is not correct when you are saying there must be a value on the right side. It can be also another variable - anything the compiler can figure out the right type.

Comment: @csg What there must be, is an expression which possesses a type. The type of that expression will be used "instead" of `var`.

Comment: @siride, I was only using x to denote a variable name, but I would never use x. I will edit for clarity.

Comment: @csg, I think you get the point I'm making?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I have edited to use your definition, instead of using value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 10;
```

is equavalent to

```
int x = 10;
```

[`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is excellent syntactic sugar.

When you write `x = 10`, your `x` must be declared before.

Answer (score 0):

**var**

It was introduced in C# 3.0

```
 1 ) var declarations are resolved at compile-time.
 2) Errors are caught at compile time.
```

When you dont know what type are you dealing with it is better to go with `var` it gets it type from the right hand side of the assignment where it is defined.

```
  var x =10;

  x=12;
```

In the first case the compiler resolved the declaration at run time

Lets assume if you would have done

```
  var x=10;

  x="I am String";
```

will throw error since the compiler has already decided that the type of `x` is System.Int32 when the value 10 was assigned to it. Now assigning a string value to it violates the type safety

**Advantages**

`var` comes in handy when you combine it with the c# 3 anonymous types and generics anonymous types are still clr types but you can't have the type name at coding time

However it is better to use naming conventions for better readability

Comment: is this correct ?   var x=10;

  x="I am String"; i can't able to modify the int to string. since var is dynamic type right ?

Comment: @SivaRajini At compile time when the Compiler encounters `var x=10` It assigns `Int` Datatype to it as a result the datataypwe has changed..... Now hereafter  any value that `x` holds whould be only and only `Int`

Answer (score 0):

The **var** aliases any type in C# and its type will be determined by C# compiler or it is implicitly typed.

But in

```
x = 12;
```

you have to **explicity** determine the type and for example write :

```
int x= 12;
```

Using **var** has no performance consideration and you can use it freely.